# Android How too convert this CSS code into style.xml

Tags: java, android, css, xml, graphic

Hi this syntax is new for me. I want to convert it into style in android.
anybody describe this?

```
background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(46% -217% -90deg,rgb(1,47,88) 0%,rgb(0,72,140) 100%); 
background-image:linear-gradient(-90deg,rgb(1,47,88) 0%,rgb(0,72,140) 100%);
width:788px;
height:143px;
```

1) I want start colour
2) I want center Colour
3) I want End Colour
4) I want an angle

LIKE

Comment: This is actually background colour of BUTTON in android

Comment: Please Help me guide me to any tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code would be something like this

```
<shape>
    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:startColor="yourStartColour"
        android:endcolor="yourEndColour"
        android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

This is the basic code for a selector, which you set as your background.
   `android:background="@drawable/yourSelector"`

Edit: The start and end colour you are searching are these 
`rgb(1,37,88)` and `rgb(0,72,140)`.

If you translate this to hex values you should replace `"yourStartColour"` with `"#012F58"` and `"yourEndColour"` with `"#00488C"`

Comment: Sir How can i find start colour from this code which is mention in question